# Deactivating a Trigger code coverage

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage, change-set

I am trying to deactivate a trigger in sandbox and push to production but an not able to validate/deploy in production due to a code coverage error. I have tried both deactivating the trigger and commenting the code entirely and am still running into the code coverage <75% error. (Between 30-45% in all my attempts)

Is there anyway to tell where the code coverage is failing or other ways to deactivate a trigger from running in production? I am a declarative admin so this is all new territory for me.

Thanks!

Apex Trigger

```
trigger ContactRoutingTrigger on Contact (before insert, after update) {//,after insert
    if (trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate) {
       System.debug('In after update');
        ContactRoutingTriggerHandler.updatebypassvalidation(Trigger.New);
        if (TriggerStaticData.isUpdated == false) {
            // Contact is existing in the org, create task for it

            // updated-8-jan-2020 paused task creation(only owner update)
           // ContactRoutingTriggerHandler.createTaskForContact(trigger.new);
        }
    }
    /*if (trigger.isAfter && trigger.isInsert) {
        System.debug('in after insert');
        ContactRoutingTriggerHandler.updatebypassvalidation(Trigger.New);
    }*/
    if (trigger.isbefore && trigger.isInsert) {
        List<Contact> contactRecords = new List<Contact>();
        List<Contact> contactWithoutMail = new List<Contact>();
        // Contact is existing in the org, create task for it
        for (Contact contactRec : trigger.new) {
            /*Updated the condition to skip process for contact created from ZoomInfo app*/
            if (!contactRec.Override_Routing_Rule__c && 
                (contactRec.DOZISF__ZoomInfo_Id__c == null || String.isBlank(contactRec.DOZISF__ZoomInfo_Id__c))) {
                if (!String.isBlank(contactRec.Email)) {
                    contactRecords.add(contactRec);
                }
                else {
                    contactWithoutMail.add(contactRec);
                }
            }
        }
        System.debug('\n***contactWithoutMail'+contactWithoutMail);
        if(!contactRecords.isEmpty()){
            ContactRoutingTriggerHandler.addContactToAccount(contactRecords);
        }
        if(!contactWithoutMail.isEmpty()){
            ContactRoutingTriggerHandler.assignToUnknown(contactWithoutMail);
        }
        //ContactRoutingTriggerHandler.createTaskForContact(contactRecords);
    }
}
```

Apex Test Class

```
@isTest
public with sharing class ContactRoutingTriggerTest {
  @TestSetup
  static void insertTestData(){
    // Scenario 1-Existing contact found
    DataFactory.createContactTestRecords(1, true, 'testMail1@gmail.com','','testContact1','Record1');
    DataFactory.createAccountTestRecords(1, true, 'www.testexistingdomain.com', 'Test Account 1');
    DataFactory.createAccountTestRecords(1, true, 'testexistingdomain2.com', 'Test Account 4');
    DataFactory.createAccountTestRecords(1, true, 'www.testexistingdomain2.com', 'Test Account 2');
    //createMetadata
    }

  // Updated -8-Jan-2019; commented task creation logic
  @isTest   
  public static void contactFoundTest() {
    Contact existingRecord = [SELECT Id,NAme,Email FROM Contact];
    existingRecord.MailingState = 'Connecticut';
    existingRecord.Territory__c = 'Northeast';
    System.Test.startTest();
        update existingRecord;
    System.Test.stopTest();

    //List<Task> insertedTasks = [SELECT Id FROM Task WHERE WhoId = :existingRecord.Id];

    // Check if task is created for contact
    //System.assert(insertedTasks.size() > 0); 
  }

  @isTest   
  public static void accountDomainFoundTest() {
    List<Contact> newContactRecord = DataFactory.createContactTestRecords
        (1, false, 'test@testexistingdomain.com', 'Test Account 2','testContact2','record2');
    List<Account> insertedAccount = 
        [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Website = 'www.testexistingdomain.com'];
    System.debug('\n****insertedAccount'+insertedAccount);

    System.Test.startTest();
        insert newContactRecord[0];
    System.Test.stopTest();

    Contact updatedContact = [SELECT Id,AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Email = 
    'test@testexistingdomain.com'];
    System.debug('\n************updatedContact'+updatedContact);

    // Check if contact is associated with correct account
    // System.assert(updatedContact.AccountId == insertedAccount[0].Id);    
  }

  @isTest   
  public static void accountWebsiteFoundTest() {
    List<Contact> newContactRecord = DataFactory.createContactTestRecords
        (1, false, 'test@testexistingNondomain.com', 'Test Account 22','testContact2','record2');
    newContactRecord[0].Website__c = 'www.testexistingdomain.com';
    List<Account> insertedAccount = 
        [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Website = 'www.testexistingdomain.com'];
    insertedAccount[0].BillingState = 'WS';
    insertedAccount[0].Territory__c = 'West';
    insertedAccount[0].BillingCountry = 'US';
    update insertedAccount[0];
    System.debug('\n****insertedAccount'+insertedAccount);

    System.Test.startTest();
        insert newContactRecord[0];
    System.Test.stopTest();

    Contact updatedContact = [SELECT Id,AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Email = 
    'test@testexistingNondomain.com'];
    System.debug('\n************updatedContact'+updatedContact);

    // Check if contact is associated with correct account
    // System.assert(updatedContact.AccountId == insertedAccount[0].Id);    
  }

  @isTest   
  public static void accountNameFoundTest() {
    List<Contact> newContactRecord = DataFactory.createContactTestRecords
        (1, false, 'testMail2@testexistingdomain.com', 'Test Account 1','t3','r3');
    //newContactRecord[0].MailingState = 'Connecticut';
    ///newContactRecord[0].Territory__c = 'Northeast';
    List<Account> insertedAccount = 
        [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Website = 'www.testexistingdomain.com'];
    
    System.debug('\n****insertedAccount'+insertedAccount);

    System.Test.startTest();
        insert newContactRecord[0];
    System.Test.stopTest();

    Contact updatedContact = [SELECT Id,AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Email = 
    'testMail2@testexistingdomain.com'];
    System.debug('\n************updatedContact'+updatedContact);

    // Check if contact is associated with correct account
    // System.assert(updatedContact.AccountId == insertedAccount[0].Id);    
  }

/*Method to assign Unknown Account*/
@isTest   
  public static void unknownAccountNameFoundTest() {
      List<Contact> conList = DataFactory.createContactTestRecords(1, true, '','','testContact3','Record3');
      
      List<Contact> updatedContacts = [Select Id,Name,AccountId,Account.Name from Contact where Id IN :conList];
      system.assertEquals(null, conList[0].Account.Name);
      system.assertEquals(updatedContacts[0].Account.Name,'_Unknown_');
  }
  
    /*Method to check whether the account gets updated or not if already an  account is populated on contact*/
@isTest   
  public static void accountDoesNotUpdateTest() {
      List<Account> accList = DataFactory.createAccountTestRecords(1, true, 'www.testingexistingdomain.com', 'Account Testing 10');
      Contact con = new Contact();
      con.DOZISF__ZoomInfo_Id__c = 'Test123';
      con.Email = 'test@testingexistingdomain.com';
      con.AccountId = accList[0].Id;
      con.FirstName = 'testContact3';
      con.LastName = 'Record3';
      Test.startTest();
      insert con;
      Test.stopTest();
      List<Contact> updatedContacts = [Select Id,Name,AccountId,Account.Name from Contact where Id =:con.Id];
      system.assertNOTEquals(updatedContacts[0].Account.Name,'_Unknown_');
  }
    
//   @isTest   
//   public static void bulkInsertTest() {
//     List<Contact> contactsToInsert = new List<Contact>();
//     List<Contact> newContactRecord1 = DataFactory.createContactTestRecords
//         (1, false, 'test2@testexistingdomain.com', 'TestNonExisrtingName','t4','r4');
//     List<Contact> newContactRecord2 = DataFactory.createContactTestRecords
//         (1, false, 'test3@testexistingdomain.com', 'TestNonExisrtingName','t5','r5');
//     List<Contact> newContactRecord3 = DataFactory.createContactTestRecords(1, false, '', '','t6','r6');
//     List<Contact> newContactRecord4 = DataFactory.createContactTestRecords
//         (1, false, 'test4@testexistingnondomain.com', 'TestNonExisrtingName','t7','r7');
//     List<Contact> newContactRecord5 = DataFactory.createContactTestRecords
//         (1, false, 'test5@testexistingdomain.com', '','t8','r8');
//         List<Contact> newContactRecord6 = DataFactory.createContactTestRecords
//         (1, false, '', '','t8','r8');

//     contactsToInsert.add(newContactRecord1[0]);
//     contactsToInsert.add(newContactRecord2[0]);
//     contactsToInsert.add(newContactRecord3[0]);
//     contactsToInsert.add(newContactRecord4[0]);
//     contactsToInsert.add(newContactRecord5[0]);
//     contactsToInsert.add(newContactRecord6[0]);


//     List<Account> insertedAccount = 
//         [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Website = 'www.testexistingdomain.com'];
//     System.debug('\n****insertedAccount'+insertedAccount);
//     List<Account> insertedAccountName = 
//         [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Test Account 2'];

//     System.Test.startTest();
//         insert contactsToInsert;
//     System.Test.stopTest();

//     List<Contact> updatedContacts = [SELECT Id,AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Email = 
//     'test2@testExistingDomain.com'];
//     System.debug('\n************updatedContact'+updatedContacts);

//     // Check if contact is associated with correct account
//     //System.assert(updatedContacts[0].AccountId == insertedAccount[0].Id);    
//     //.assert(updatedContacts[1].AccountId == insertedAccount[0].Id);    
//   }
}
```

Comment: If deleting it instead is an option for you, that will likely be easier

Comment: I guess currently you are selecting default option while deploying, One trick you can do is Run specified tests while deploying and run only this test class. It should work